# Why we are not able to use Nav in constructor instead of @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav in ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I am new to ionic,i am trying to understand below code.I can't understand what is the "NAV" for.why we use that NAV in @viewchild().I am able to access the MenuController by using it in constructor,and why not able to use that NAV in constructor.

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, MenuController, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';

import { HelloIonicPage } from '../pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage = HelloIonicPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public menu: MenuController,
    public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Hello Ionic', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'My First List', component: ListPage }
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // close the menu when clicking a link from the menu
    this.menu.close();
    // navigate to the new page if it is not the current page
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because any components that are navigation controllers are children of the root component so they aren't available to be injected.

By adding a reference variable to the `ion-nav`, you can use `@ViewChild` to get an instance of the `Nav` component, which is a navigation controller (it extends `NavController`)

**update**:

we use `@ViewChild` when we want to access child component and call methods or access instance variables that are available on the child. `NavController` is the base class for navigation controller components like `Nav` and `Tab`so you can access it via constructor but `Nav` extends `NavController`(its the child of `NavController`) so you can't directly access in constructor then by `@ViewChild` you can access it.

Comment: will you please elaborate it because i'm little bit confused.

Comment: @johnny just updated the answer with more details hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The answer can be found [here (v3)](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-the-root-component)

> **Navigating from the Root component**
>
> What if you want to control
>   navigation from your root app component? You can't inject
>   NavController because any components that are navigation controllers
>   are children of the root component so they aren't available to be
>   injected.
>
> By adding a reference variable to the ion-nav, you can use @ViewChild
>   to get an instance of the Nav component, which is a navigation
>   controller (it extends NavController):